# Capybara setting a field results in 'Attempt to set readonly element with value'

Tags: capybara, firefox-marionette

With Firefox 47.0, I switched to the Marionette driver.
Using Capybara, when I try to fill in a field, Capybara responds with 'Attempt to set readonly element with value' and doesn't set the field value. Querying the readonly flag gives a 'false', so what's wrong?

```
find_by_id('account_username').set(@username)
Attempt to set readonly element with value: test-1466414209-898496
*This will raise an exception in a future version of Capybara

find_by_id('account_username')['readonly']
=> "false"
```

Using Capybara 2.7.1 and geckodriver 0.8.0 on OSX.

Hope this is the right place to ask.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [this issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1710), you need to be using the marionette branch of Capybara for that to work. Marionette support between geckodriver and selenium is not yet fully working, and not a fully functional replacement for firefoxdriver. For now, you're better off reverting to Firefox 46 or waiting for the Firefox 47.0.1 release as mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1709) github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/1709